# Changing User's Header Orientation

Tags: swift, core-location, mapbox

Is there a way I can change the user's heading orientation? If I were using CoreLocation and Apple MapKit I could simply do `manager.headingOrientation = CLDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft` but it seems I can't invert the heading.

Comment: Tell the user to look behind them?

Comment: No. In CoreLocation you can change the device orientation so the heading information is correct. I need to do that with Mapbox

Answer (score 0):

The Mapbox iOS SDK [handles device rotation heading orientation automatically](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/d9a2a845dec1697f6b68b6aa4c4a49b0c2738329/platform/ios/src/MGLMapView.mm#L3956-L3987). You can access this heading via [`MGLMapView.userLocation.heading`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.2.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(py)userLocation), when it’s available.

If you need to process the raw heading differently or need it available when heading tracking mode is disabled, you should instantiate your own location manager.

If we’re doing something incorrectly with the heading, we’d love to hear about it [on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/new).